# Can Bloodrush be countered with an instant that destroys attacking creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

#### The Setup:

It is my opponent's turn. He has an [Elvish Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Mystic) on the field (1/1). He declares his Elvish Mystic as an attacker, then activates his [Ghor-Clan Rampager](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghor-Clan%20Rampager)'s Bloodrush ability from his hand, with the target being his attacking Elvish Mystic.

#### My Response:

I have a [Wring Flesh](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wring%20Flesh) in my hand and the mana to cast it. I target his Elvish Mystic.

#### Outcomes/Question:

If my instant does not take precedence, Elvish Mystic becomes a 5/5 from Bloodrush, then drops to a 2/4 from Wring Flesh.

If my instant takes precedence, this means the Elvish Mystic ends up in the graveyard.

What happens to the Ghor-Clan Rampager? Does Ghor-Clan Rampager still cast Bloodrush (on an invalid target) and get discarded, or does it remain in his hand without activating?

Comment: yes. http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6016/3128

Comment: Worth noting: this applies to basically every scenario where someone wants to cast a spell on something, and you get rid of that something before that spell resolves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The blood rush card fizzles and goes to the graveyard.**

To answer the question in the title: Yes.

Your understanding is correct. Since your Wring Flesh is on the stack above the bloodrush card, then it happens before the bloodrush is applied.

Since the card's bloodrush ability was activated, it is discarded. The first part of the bloodrush ability says the card is to be discarded.

Comment: bloodrush does not cast the card, this is an important disctinction for storm, countering and other factors. so the answer should probably be clarified

Comment: very good point.

Comment: It might be important to note that the check to see if a creature dies happens after each spell or ability, and it does not matter how many things are still on the stack. Since Wring Flesh fires first, it doesn't matter what else is there.